# Profile-Guided Optimization (PGO) kinds in Xcode

Tags: xcode

After reading the [Xcode PGO documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/xcode_profile_guided_optimization/pgo-tasks/pgo-tasks.html) it's unclear what PGO way it uses. Is it FrontEnd PGO (`-fprofile-instr-generate` in Clang), IR PGO (`-fprofile-generate`), CSIR PGO (`-fcs-profile-generate`) or any combination of all these PGO kinds?

Comment: Which practical end-user problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: I want to optimize the CPU usage of my application with Profile-Guided Optimization.

Comment: I assumed as much, after reading all your questions :-) But you are basically asking two questions here (kind of PGO, and platform support), which makes answering difficult.

Comment: Sorry, my bad. Edited the question and extracted the question about supported by PGO platforms into a separate one - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/467266/supported-platforms-by-pgo-in-xcode