# Supported platforms by PGO in Xcode

Tags: xcode

What target platforms are supported for PGO optimization? macOS, iOS, tvOS - what exactly? I didn't find this information in the Xcode documentation about PGO.

We evaluate using PGO for all our products for better CPU optimization across as many target platforms as possible.